# Sass @mixin - prevent selector repetition and combine all styles under single selector

Tags: css, sass

I have written this @mixin to set styles for light and dark theme in one line.

```
@mixin setThemeDynamicCSSRule($property, $light-theme-value, $dark-theme-value) {
     #{$property}: #{$light-theme-value};
    
      .dark-mode & {
          #{$property}: #{$dark-theme-value}   
      }
}

body {
    @include setThemeDynamicCSSRule(color, black, white);
    @include setThemeDynamicCSSRule(background-color, white, black);
    @include setThemeDynamicCSSRule(font-size, 16px, 32px);
}
```

This returns me:

```
body {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.dark-mode body {
  color: white;
}
.dark-mode body {
  background-color: black;
}
.dark-mode body {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

it keeps repeating `.dark-mode body` selector for each individual `setThemeDynamicCSSRule()` call.

It still does the job but ideally I would like css to compile to:

```
body {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.dark-mode body {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Probably it is better to use this plugin which will resolve my final CSS output to what I want https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-combine-duplicated-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the way your are looking for ... but thinking forward it is the wanted result. And mayby an easier and more neat way to organize your special theme properties in one place.

Wrap your different theme property/values at to a nested map. Than use an adapted mixin.

```
$themes: (

    color: (
        'light': 'black',
        'dark': 'white',
    ),
    background-color: (
        'light': 'white',
        'dark': 'black',
    ),
    font-size: (
        'light': 16px,
        'dark': 32px,
    ),

);

@mixin setThemeStyles($themes){

    @each $property, $values in $themes {
        #{$property}: map-get($values, 'light' );
    }

    .dark-mode & {
        @each $property, $values in $themes{
            #{$property}: map-get($values, 'dark');
        }
    }
    

}

body {
    @include setThemeStyles($themes);
}



//######>> RESULT IS YOUR WANTED CSS
body {
  color: "black";
  background-color: "white";
  font-size: 16px;
}
.dark-mode body {
  color: "white";
  background-color: "black";
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is great solution as well. But I was trying to avoid this approach because I like the idea that I do not have to maintain a separate map with element scoped CSS rules, but set styles in one line mixin inside selector.